# How to obtain the location of cacerts of the default java installation?

Tags: java, security

I am looking on how how to obtain the location of `cacerts` of the default java installation, when you do not have `JAVA_HOME` or `JRE_HOME` defined.

I need a solution that works at least for `OS X` and `Linux`.

Yes. `java -v` is assumed to work :)

Answer (score 240):

Under **Linux**, to find the location of `$JAVA_HOME`:

```
readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::"
```

the `cacerts` are under `lib/security/cacerts`:

```
$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::")lib/security/cacerts
```

Under **mac OS X** , to find `$JAVA_HOME` run:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home
```

the `cacerts` are under `Home/lib/security/cacerts`:

```
$(/usr/libexec/java_home)/lib/security/cacerts
```

**UPDATE: JDK 8 (or prior)**

The code above was tested on a computer with a JRE installed.
When using a JDK for Java 8 (or prior), [as pR0Ps said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27971915/369977), it's at

```
$(/usr/libexec/java_home)/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

For Java 9 and above, both JRE and JDK use `$(/usr/libexec/java_home)/lib/security/cacerts`.

Comment: In OS X, the "official" way to find JAVA_HOME is running `/usr/libexec/java_home`

Comment: @DanielSerodio, agreed. `/usr/libexec/java_home` gives me a different answer from the `readlink`-based command above, and the former seems to be correct, in that it contains the `cacerts` file.

Comment: @DanielSerodio and AndrewFerrier thanks guys, answer updated.

Comment: @Kuf My JDK does not have this lib/security folder on Mac Yosemite. I am positive that i am in the right $JAVA_HOME

Comment: @BrianVanover answer updated. If it doesn't work for you please specify '/usr/libexec/java_home' output and JDK version

Comment: On OSX 10.10.5 the security folder is under:
Home/jre/lib/security

Comment: Your command on my Linux system says No such file or directory as there is no /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_162/lib/security/cacerts. Is the rule different for jre an jdk?

Comment: I ran this just now on Mojave with Zulu installed via brew (basically the .dmg installer) and it didn't work. I had to remove `jre/` from the path: `$(/usr/libexec/java_home)/lib/security/cacerts`

Comment: how come the "/usr/libexec/java_home" is different than "echo $JAVA_HOME" ? shouldn't they be the same path?

Comment: On MacOS Big Sur this was at `$(/usr/libexec/java_home)/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts`

Comment: This doesn't appear to work in Ubuntu

Answer (score 55):

As of OS X 10.10.1 (Yosemite), the location of the `cacerts` file has been changed to

```
$(/usr/libexec/java_home)/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

Answer (score 16):

If you need to access those certs programmatically it is best to not use the file at all, but access it via the trust manager. The following code is from a OpenJDK [Test](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~martin/webrevs/jdk/CacertsExplorer/test/jdk/javax/net/ssl/sanity/CacertsExplorer.java.html) case (which makes sure the built cacerts collection is not empty):

```
TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory =
    TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("PKIX");
trustManagerFactory.init((KeyStore) null);
TrustManager[] trustManagers =
    trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();
X509TrustManager trustManager =
    (X509TrustManager) trustManagers[0];
X509Certificate[] acceptedIssuers =
    trustManager.getAcceptedIssuers();
```

So you don’t have to deal with file location or keystore password.

Comment: This is not reading the certificate installed in cacerts. i am able to if using file path and password

Comment: Yup @SomnathSingh is correct, this is definitely not reading the root cacerts. I have no idea what this is actually reading though.

Comment: It reads the cacerts file in the same way the JDK implementation is using the default implementation.

Comment: Nice pointer, but I do not see how above code reveals the *location* of the cacerts file? It accesses the _content_, which is good to know, but does not answer the OP question. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes the answer reads "not use the file at all"

Answer (score 16):

For `Java 9` onwards, it's in

> `${JAVA_HOME}/lib/security/cacerts`

as opposed to the usual

> `${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/security/cacerts`

Answer (score 12):

In MacOS Mojave, the location is:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_192.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

If using sdkman to manage java versions, the cacerts is in

```
~/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/jre/lib/security
```

Comment: NOTE: For current versions of sdkman w/ JDK 11, the location is `~/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/lib/security`

Answer (score 7):

In High Sierra, the **cacerts** is located at : `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts`

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, the **cacerts** is located at: `/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts`

```
$ java --version
openjdk 11.0.11 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

```
$ ls -lah /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/security/cacerts*
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/security/cacerts -> /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts
```

Comment: This is also true in 22.04

Answer (score 1):

You can also consult readlink -f "`which java`". However it might not work for all binary wrappers. It is most likely better to actually start a Java class.

Answer (score 0):

for my Mac running MacOS Sonomoa 14.3.1, JDK8 installed from homebrew:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/openjdk@8/1.8.0-382_1/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```