# Where should the jssecacerts file be placed on Mac?

Tags: active-directory, jvm, ssl-certificate, osx-yosemite, ldapconnection

I am trying to connect a webapp, running in Tomcat 7.0.34 on a Mac, OS/X 10.10 (Yosemite), to a secure AD server.  I get this error:

```
org.springframework.ldap.CommunicationException: qlty-test-ad:636; nested exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: qlty-test-ad:636 [Root exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target]
at org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapUtils.convertLdapException(LdapUtils.java:100)
at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.createContext(AbstractContextSource.java:266)
at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.getContext(AbstractContextSource.java:106)
at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.getReadOnlyContext(AbstractContextSource.java:125)
at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.executeReadOnly(LdapTemplate.java:792)
at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.lookup(LdapTemplate.java:822)
at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.lookupContext(LdapTemplate.java:1315)
at com.enonic.cms.ee.ldap.LdapConnector.lookup(LdapConnector.java:261)
at com.enonic.cms.ee.ldap.LdapRemoteUserStorePlugin.verifyConnection(LdapRemoteUserStorePlugin.java:489)
... 87 more
```

So, I am missing a server certificate.  I downloaded it with [InstallCert](https://github.com/escline/InstallCert/blob/master/InstallCert.java) and got the jssecacerts file, and as far as I can understand, I just need to place it in a folder where my JVM can find it and use it.  First I tried, directly in the jdk:

`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/`

Descriptions suggest there should be a "security" folder inside "lib", but there isn't.  I tried to create one, then put the jssecacerts file here, but it did not help.

Then, I found a reference to this folder:

`/System/Library/Java/Support/CoreDeploy.bundle/Contents/Home/lib/security/`

It allready contained the "cacerts" file, so I thought I was on to something, but placing "jssecacerts" here does not help either.  There is also

`/Library/Java/Home/lib/security`

which contains symbolic links to both files ("cacerts" and "jssecacerts").

**Does anybody know where I should put `jssecacerts`?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a relevant article on StackOverflow here: [How to obtain the location of cacerts of the default java installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936685/how-to-obtain-the-location-of-cacerts-of-the-default-java-installation)

On Java 1.8 it should be placed under this folder:

`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_xx.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security`

I did not find any security directory under the JDK, but I suppose it's using the same one as the JRE.

To find the Java on Mac:

`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`

Comment: This is what I have tried.  My JAVA_HOME is defined.  It is the first folder listed above.  "cacerts" is placed in /Library/Java/Home/lib/security, via a symbolic link to /System/Library/Java/Support/CoreDeploy.bundle/Contents/Home/lib/security, but for some reason jssecacerts is not loaded, even if it is placed in the same place in the same way.

Comment: Putting it under $JAVA/HOME/jre/lib/security solved the problem.