# Java Security - Missing lib/security directory

Tags: java, maven, security, ssl-certificate, osx-yosemite

I am trying to build the [Apache Storm Starter Project](https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/examples/storm-starter) using `Maven` on Mac OS X 10.10

I am failing the build because of a `SunCertPathBuilderException` which suggests I need to add a security certificate in my `$JAVA_HOME/lib/security` directory.

This [Stackoverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936685/how-to-obtain-the-location-of-cacerts-of-the-default-java-installation) suggests I am looking in the correct place.

> JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home

However, my `$JAVA_HOME/lib` directory contains no such security subdirectory. The contents are:

> ant-javafx.jar    ct.sym      dt.jar      ir.idl      javafx-mx.jar   jconsole.jar    missioncontrol  orb.idl     packager.jar    sa-jdi.jar  tools.jar   visualvm

Why don't I have this security directory? Also, is this really necessary for being able to build an example project from Apache?

How can I set up my JDK to build in situations like this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

if `$JAVA_HOME` refers to a JDK, then the `security` folder exists at:

```
$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security
```

not

```
$JAVA_HOME/lib/security
```

Comment: Thanks! This was a careless oversight on my part. I missed that this was explained in the second answer on the original post. Do you know how I can add a cert to this so I can build the Apache project?

Comment: @BrianVanover I believe that you can import the certificate into `cacerts` keystore using `keytool`.

Comment: The path is mentioned incorrectly in the Java Docs too: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/p11guide.html#Requirements