# java-6 installation problem on my mac book

Tags: macos-sierra, java-6

I have installed java 6 on my mac OS high sierra version 10.13.6 from the apple support: https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US.
When I try to locate my cacerts file in that java 6 installation, I find it under:
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security

The cacerts file is linked to /System/Library/Java/Support/CoreDeploy.bundle/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts

I find that the folder /System/Library/Java/Support/CoreDeploy.bundle/Contents/Home/lib/security does not exist at all.

As a result, I can't import any certificates to my java 6 keystore.

Has anyone encountered this issue? Is there any suggestion on how this can be solved?

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936685/how-to-obtain-the-location-of-cacerts-of-the-default-java-installation ?

Comment: I have both jdk8 and jdk6 installed on my mac book. That folder:$(/usr/libexec/java_home)/jre/lib/security/ is under java 8 installation.